# Derived category supported in a Serre subcategory of a locally noetherian category

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, abelian-categories

This is a cross-post from math.stackexchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251692/derived-category-supported-in-a-serre-subcategory-of-a-locally-noetherian-catego, since I didn't get any answers there.

It is known that $Coh(O_X)\subseteq QCoh(O_X)$ is a Serre subcategory for a Noetherian scheme $X$ and $D^−(Coh(O_X))→D^−_{Coh(O_X)}(QCoh(OX))$ is an equivalence. A sketch of the proof can be found (for example) in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/perfect.pdf and the proof relies on Lemma 17.4 of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/derived.pdf and the following fact:

For any surjection from a quasi-coherent $O_X$-module $\mathcal{G}$ to a coherent $O_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$, there is a coherent submodule of $\mathcal{G}$ which surjects onto $\mathcal{F}$.

It is later stated that "one can write a quasi-coherent sheaf as the filtered union of its coherent submodules and then one of these will do the job". I think, at least locally, I know what's going on: say $M\rightarrow N$
is a surjection with $N$ a finitely generated module, we can choose the submodule of $M$ (finitely) generated by preimages of the generators of $N$ and this submodule is the "one of these" that finishes the job.

My questions is whether this can be generalied to "nice" situations, for example, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a locally Noetherian Grothendieck category, consider the Serre subcategory $Noeth(\mathcal{G}$), is it true that one always has $D^−(Noeth(\mathcal{G}))\cong D^−_{Noeth(\mathcal G)}(\mathcal G)$?

As $\mathcal G$ is locally Noetherian, any object is the direct limit of its Noetherian subobjects, is it possible/how to choose a Noetherian subobject that will "do the job"?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should look at this article:Positselski, Leonid; Schnürer, Olaf M.
Unbounded derived categories of small and big modules: is the natural functor fully faithful?
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 225 (2021), no. 11, Paper No. 106722, 23 pp.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference.